# Browser caching the image,after refreshing the src of <img /> with jQuery, Image not changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jcrop, client-side-scripting

Can we force an image to be changed after changing the new  URL..?
In my case... Am putting source of image when user puts the URL of any picture into text box..

OnBlur: Image Shows on the Browser.. But Problem is that after loading the image , when I put another URL into textbox and deleting the prevoius... Images Dosen't appear.. However source of Image is changed... here is my code

```
$("#urltxt").blur(function () {
                var source = $("#urltxt").val();
                $("#target").attr("src", source);
                $('#target').Jcrop({
                    setSelect: [100, 100, 50, 50],
                    onRelease: clearCoords
                }
            });
$("#urltxt").keyup(function () {
                src = $('#target').attr('src');
                // check for existing ? and remove if found
                queryPos = src.indexOf('?');
                if (queryPos != -1) {
                    src = src.substring(0, queryPos);
                }
                $('#target').attr('src', $("#urltxt").val() + '?' + Math.random());

            });
```

and my HTML tags are

```
<img src="" id="target"/>

<input id="urltxt" name="url" placeholder="URL" />
```

Any Suggestions will be appreciated.. Thx..

Comment: i tried many examples from stackoverflow and google but nothing works

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this on page_load:

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
```

For more details:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w9s3a17d(v=vs.71).aspx

(or) you can try to add a unique string at the end of image as shown:

```
<img src="/path/to/image.jpg?<%=DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()%>" />
```